# How can I prevent javascript errors in my selenium tests from hanging my build system?

Tags: javascript, selenium

We are having a problem with our selenium tests which run in IE on a virtual machine. Whenever there is a javascript error, a popup shows up and puts our system into a 'stuck' state - a user has to go clear that and restart the selenium test run. Is there a way to prevent the javascript error popup from putting the system into its stuck state? Would setting window.error be of any help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck '**Display a notification about every script error**' ?